# How to call Git Bash from Windows and preserve autocrlf

Tags: windows, git, bash, line-endings

I have automated python scripts for git versioning system. It works on linux, but I have some problems on windows. I will go directly to the core of the problem...

There are sources ended by LF (not CRLF) and Windows Git Bash can handle it perfectly (checkout as Windows style and commit as unix style).

When I open Git Bash and type "git status" I get

```
your branch is up-to-date.....nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

When I open cmd.exe and I write "git status"

```
....
modified: example.h
modified: example.cpp
....
```

the modification is just because cmd.exe does not handle autocrlf. the monification is just in line endings.

I tried a workaround:

```
c:\myrepo>echo git status|"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

output:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.9.2-preview20140411)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

xxx@yy /c/myrepo (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

xxx@yy /c/myrepo (master)
$

xxx@yy4 /c/myrepo (master)
$ logout
```

This almost solves my issue, but there is an annoying welcome message which makes my script not working.

Another workaround could be without --login -i:

```
c:\myrepo>echo git status|"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe"
```

output:

```
....
modified: example.h
modified: example.cpp
....
```

The command without  --login -i solves the welcome issue, but it does not autoclrf.

I could [delete welcome mesage file](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/105) , but I want my project to be usable after checkout without deleting anything in system.

Is there some painless solution?

Comment: Do you have `core.autocrlf` turned on for this repo? Run `git config core.autocrlf` to find out and `git config core.autocrlf true` to enable it.

Comment: Yes, I have, but only is git Bash. Git config core.autocrlf = true. the problem is that context of cmd.exe is different than ..git\bin\sh.exe

Comment: What if you set it explicitly in cmd by running `git config core.autocrlf true`?

Comment: There is nothing when I run cmd.exe and type git config core.autocrlf. When I set git config core.autocrlf true, it is working now!!!! It is possible to make cmd.exe and git Bash to share the ssettings?

Comment: I think it's related to `$HOME` and where `.gitconfig` is stored. You can try to experiment with `$HOME`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and also try to set `core.autocrlf` to repo explicitly (via `git config --local core.autocrlf true` when your current directory is in repo), though it should write to local config by default.

Comment: I solved it in way that I put git config --local core.autocrlf true at the beginning of the script. Thank you.